# 2D Matrix using Singly Linked Lists in Java

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, singly-linked-list

I am having a hard time of how to approach the problem of creating a 2D matrix in Java using a Singly Linked List as the underlying data structure. The goal is to have the user input the number of rows and columns and we create this matrix and the user has the option to display, insert, fill, or compute the row and column sums. Each node in the matrix should have a right pointer and a down pointer (when applicable). If you could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

EX) Display function of a 2x3 matrix should look something like this

00->01->02

10->11->12

00 should point down to 10, 01 to 11 and 02 to 12

hopefully that visual representation helps

Thanks!

Comment: Do you already know what's a singly linked list and the common methods present in the the data structure?

Answer (score 0):

If node in your list have references to more than two elements (previous and next), it is not a list, it's more complicated data structure.

For your problem I recommend you to create function, which allows you to transfer Cartesian coordinates into linear coordinates. Then add elements into list by linear coordinates (I think, ArrayList is more suitable for you). Technically, your matrix will be stored in a single list.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of a simple singly linked list should be easily available online. A few modifications are needed in the linked list (Assuming singly here means unidirectional, right and down, but not left and up):

```
 1. You'll need to two variables, to keep track of rows and columns.
 2. You'll need a size variable, increment it after each element is added.
 3. Modify the add method, so that whenever the size is > column (when a column fills up), point your down pointer of above node to the adding node, node[size-column].down = thisNode. (assuming you insert them column by column)
 4. Display method should be pretty easy, iterate through column, if index > column, move to a new line.
 5. Compute Row/Column sums by iterating through .next/ .down, (while hasnext, sum += next)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution code for this problem here:
https://github.com/manoj7shekhawat/dataStructures/blob/master/Examples/Chap05/matrix/matrixApp.java